# Characteristic polynomial of the tree

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

How can one show that a coefficient of $\lambda^{n-2k}$ in characteristic polynomial of the tree is a number of matchings of size k in this tree. $n$ is a number of vertexes in the tree.

Comment: Apply the definition of determinant as a signed sum of all permuted products.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [characteristic polynomial of the adjacency matrix of a tree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178744/characteristic-polynomial-of-the-adjacency-matrix-of-a-tree)